# JSTL Increment date string in forEach loop

Tags: date, jsp, foreach, jstl

I have this `<c:forEach>` loop in JSTL. The date string is in the format `MM/dd/yyyy` and at the end of the for loop I would like to increment the day by 1 each time.

```xml
<c:set var="currentDate" value="${param.STARTDATE}"/>
  <c:forEach begin="1" end="7" varStatus="loop">

  <!-- Doing other stuff with the date as a string here -->
                            
  <c:set var="nextDay" value="currentDate + someDateCalculation" />
  <c:set var="currentDate" value="${nextDay}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse a date string from a parameter using a class [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), then convert it to a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). Then you can increment a day using it's API. If you want to use a date as string then you should format it with the formatter using a specified pattern.

```xml
<c:set var="currentDate" value="${LocalDateTime.parse(param.STARTDATE, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy"))}" />
<c:forEach begin="1" end="7" varStatus="loop">

  <!-- Doing other stuff with the date as a string here -->
  <c:set var="currentDateAsString" value="${currentDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy"))}" />  

  <!-- Increment a current date by 1 day -->                            
  <c:set var="currentDate" value="${currentDate.plusDays(1)}" />
</c:forEach>
```